# Set regex for decimal number with jquery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I use jquery validator plugin to validate my form. In form exists `currency` field, which needs the value, that appropriate to this regexp `^\d{1,9}(\.\d{1,2})?$`. Below is my `js` code snippet.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
        ignore:[],
        rules:{
            currency:{
                required: true
            }
            .....
        }
}
```

**Question:**  How can I set above mentioned regexp to `currency` field with `jquery` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a custom rule:

```
$.validator.addMethod('currency', function(value, element, regexp) {
    var re = /^\d{1,9}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
}, '');
```

and then:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    ignore:[],
    rules: {
        currency: {
            currency: true
        }
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: What about localization? not all countries use "." or "," the way it is used the regex above.