# validate input field using jquery validate plugin for decimal

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an input field as below

```
<input value="30" id="custom2" name="custom2" class="form-control valid"
       placeholder="Total purchase amount" type="text">
```

Need it to be validated using jquery validate plugin such that it takes minimum 2 decimals and no more than 2 decimals and minimum 30$. In other words if user input 40, it should become 40.00, if user input 40.1 it should not validate until 2 decimals.

This is what I was thinking for the rules section

```
custom2: {
   required: true,
   number: true,
   min: 30
},
```

But how to state that it needs to be **at least 2 decimal and no more than 2 decimal**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517562/set-regex-for-decimal-number-with-jquery-validator-plugin - check this out

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
$.validator.addMethod('currency', function(value, element, regexp) {
    var re = /^\d{1,9}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
}, 'Should enter only numericals.');
```

Comment: Thanks.. However I want it a bit different.. I did saw that jira ticket. but it is not exactly what I want. I want it to be atleast 2 decimal and no more than 2 decimal. With that solution or yours, we can have 30 and it will validate.. howwver I want user to enter atleast 2 decimal?